# How to dynamically change menu in onCreateOptionsMenu

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock, android-menu

I have small problem and I'd like to solve it with dynamical menu:

```
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(com.actionbarsherlock.view.Menu menu) {
    switch(Globals.editMode){
    case Globals.MODE_NONE:
        getSupportMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.imagehandlingmain_menu, menu);
        break;
    case Globals.MODE_MOVE:
        getSupportMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.savecancel_menu, menu);
        break;
    case Globals.MODE_ROTATE:
        getSupportMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.savecancel_menu, menu);
        break;
    case Globals.MODE_SCALE:
        getSupportMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.savecancel_menu, menu);
        break;
    }
    //getSupportMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.imagehandlingmain_menu, menu);
    return true;
```

I have two menus, menu where you can select work mode, and while in certain work mode menu should change to "cancel" and "save".

So the idea is that you enter to one of modes, and then if you decide not to save your work you can cancel it and return to previous state.

Now, as I assumed onCreateOptionsMenu is called only once, so how could / should I "reload" the whole menu when needed?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You can use [`Activity.invalidateOptionsMenu()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#invalidateOptionsMenu%28%29). This - as the name suggests - will invalidate the current menu and consequently `Activity.onPrepareOptionsMenu()` will be called again.

Comment: As I've read in link you supplied, it consequently calls onCreateOptionsMenu(), but yes it works. Tnx!

Comment: There is also `supportInvalidateOptionsMenu()` if using the compat support library or sherlock